# Can't add an existing Java project to my Play Framework's build.sbt

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

I've been developing in Java for a while, and started playing with Play! Framework. When I develop in Java (using Eclipse), I usually convert my Java projects to maven projects, and then add them as dependencies of each other.

I know that in Play! you can add a jar to a \lib folder and it would work. But I'd like to know how to use the build.properties for this, as I believe it is the more correct and efficient method.

I've configured my Java project's pom.xml file to:

```
<groupId>com.xxx.yyy</groupId>
<artifactId>javaProj</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I've added to the project/build.properties file the following code:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
// "com.xxx.yyy" % "javaProj" % "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
)
```

I've tried the "activator dependencies" & "activator eclipse" commands, and even to run the server so that it compiles - but the classes that I'm attempting to import are still not to be found.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
// "com.xxx.yyy" % "javaProj" % "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
)
```

should go in `build.sbt` not in `project/build.properties`.